# analogRead() inside a loop always returns 0

Tags: arduino-uno, analogread

I wrote Arduino code to receive analog input from different voltage dividers connected to four pins (A0 to A4) and analog input from a temperature sensor (LM35) to A5. `analogRead` inside the for loop always returns zero whereas `analogRead` outside the for loop returns correct values.

What has to be changed to get correct values?

```
int time=0,y=0;
float volt;
String str;
int countParallel=0;
float voltage[]={0,0,0,0};
float temperature=0;
int sensors_pin[]={A1,A2,A3,A4,A5};
String x="";

// the setup rouontine runs once when you press reset;
void setup() {
  pinMode(2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(3,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(4,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(5,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(6,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(7,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setTimeout(50);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever;
void loop() {
  Serial.println(analogRead(A5)*500/1023);
  delay(1000);
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {
    int inChar = Serial.read();
    if (isDigit(inChar)) {
      x += (char)inChar;
    }
  }
  // Parallel Disharging
  //  Serial.println(x);
  if(x.toInt()==1) {
    digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
    if(countParallel<1) {
      digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
      countParallel++;
    }
   for(int i=1,x=14;i<=5;i++,x++) {
    if(i<4) {
      Serial.println(analogRead(x)*(5/1023));
      delay(100);
    } else if(i==5) {
      Serial.println(analogRead(x) * p(500/1023));
      delay(100);
    }
    if(volt<2.8){
     digitalWrite(i+1,HIGH);
   } else if(temperature>40) {
     digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
     digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
    }
  }
}

// Series Discharge
if(x.toInt()==2){
    for(int i=A0;i<=A4;i++){
      if(i<A4) {
        voltage[i] = analogRead(sensors_pin[i]) * (5/1023);
        Serial.println(10);
        delay(100);
      } else if(i==A4) {
        temperature = analogRead(sensors_pin[i])*(500/1023);
        Serial.println(9);
        delay(100);
      }
      if(volt<2.8) {
        digitalWrite(i, HIGH);
        delay(100);
      } else if(temperature>40) {
        digitalWrite(2,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(3,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(4,HIGH);
        digitalWrite(5,HIGH);
      }
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
voltage[i]=analogRead(sensors_pin[i])*(5/1023)
```

Is equivalent to

```
voltage[i]= analogRead(sensors_pin[i])*0
          = 0;
```

You are using an integer division, not a floating point divsion. `5 / 1023` evaluates to `0`, `5.0f / 1023` evalues to `0.00488..`. You have repeated this error throughout your lower loop code, which is why you're only getting `0`.

In your outer loop you printed it as

```
Serial.println(analogRead(A5)*500/1023);
```

Which will first multiply by 500, then divide by 1023, which works. But since you put the above expression in parenthesis, it was first evaluated.

Comment: As a side note, it's 1024 rather than 1023.